# Matplotlib histogram title

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to call a variable in a function of matplotlib, but it gives me an error. Maybe it's not possible.

```
sigma = float(some number)
ax1.hist(population)
ax1.set_title('blah   N = 241', 'standard deviation =',sigma)
```

It returns the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

or

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title) for `set_title` shows that it doesn't work the same way as `print`. You've provided three arguments, and the second is supposed to be a `dict` (which can be `pop`-ed). Since you've passed a string, that won't work.

Try this:

```
sigma = float(some number)
ax1.hist(population)
title = 'blah   N = 241, ' + 'standard deviation =' + str(sigma)
ax1.set_title(title)
```

Comment: title = f'blah   N = 241, standard deviation = {sigma}' is better.

Answer (score 1):

`ax.set_title()` requires that the title is one character string. You must collect all string fragments into one string before passing them to the `set_title` function:

```
ax1.set_title('blah   N = 241' + 'standard deviation =' + str(sigma))
```